# Cannot call method "getValues" of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The error returning is:

> "TypeError: Cannot call method "getValues" of undefined. (line 7, file "Code")"

```
function setDropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  selecionaRange(sht);

  var arrayValues = rng.getValues();

  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);
  ss.getRange('sheet1!A6').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}

function selecionaRange(sht) {
  if (sht.getRange("A1") == "IM") {
    return rng = sht.getRange('B1:B5');
  }
}
```

Comment: `rng` isn't defined when you are calling `getValues()` on it

Comment: change "return rng = sht.getRange('B1:B5');" line by "return sht.getRange('B1:B5');"

Comment: `rng` is created as a global variable and a value is assigned only if the `if(sht.getRange("A1") == "IM")` condition is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many thanks to you who tried to help me. I found that my problem is that was missing the .getValue() method after sht.getRange("A1")

Now it works.

```
var rng = null //or better another value
  function setDropdown() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 selecionaRange(sht);

 var arrayValues = rng.getValues();

 var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);
 ss.getRange('sheet1!A6').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}

function selecionaRange(sht) {
  if (sht.getRange("A1").getValue() == "IM") { //Here must have .getValue()
  return rng = sht.getRange('B1:B5');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function setDropdown() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 var rng = selecionaRange(sht);

 var arrayValues = rng.getValues();

 var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);
 ss.getRange('sheet1!A6').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}

function selecionaRange(sht) {
  if (sht.getRange("A1") == "IM") {
  return sht.getRange('B1:B5');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Il Maro!!!
Even if I set the var rng as global variable it didn't work.
My intention would be to set the variable rng inside the second funcion selecionaRange()

Answer (score 0):

your code starts like this:

```
function setDropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  selecionaRange(sht);

  var arrayValues = rng.getValues();
```

notice that by the line `var arrayValues = rng.getValues();` - that `rng` object you're working on is not defined. you need to define it first, get it from outside the function or get it passed as an argument- but you need it to exist before calling methods or performing ANY action on it.

Also, at the return statement inside your `selecionaRange` method, you don't need to set the `sht.getRange('B1:B5');` value to rng and then return it... just return what the function returns, like this:

`return sht.getRange('B1:B5');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gibor!
It didn't work; 
My intention is to define it inside other funcion selecionaRange() and then return the chosen range to the rng variable